# How to get all values of text inputs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with a column of pre-populated text inputs:

```
    <table><tr><td>...</td><td><input class="unique_class" value="value1"/></td></tr>...
```

I gave each input box the same css class that only that element has (unique_class). I was hoping that I could use jQuery.val() to grab an array of all the input values with the css class in the table like this (I have done something similar with checkbox values):

```
    var values = $('.unique_class').val();
```

However, I only am getting the value of the last input in the table. Is there a simple 'fast' way to this without a for-loop iteration? This table can get be very large (100+ rows)?

Comment: If you are associating "fast" with "few lines of code", you don't understand programming...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an array of values you should use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method:

```
var values = $('.unique_class').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

Also note, how you use [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) method to convert jQuery array-like collection to actual array.

Comment: Can i ask why you use `.val()` with `.map()` ? Is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
 var values = $('td.unique_class').val();
```