# How to get multiple textbox values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the values of multiple textboxes using the same script. In my script, I am getting the textbox values before and after change of value for a single textbox. How can I write the same JavaScript for multiple textboxes?

```
<div align="center">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="bill" name="billid" class="update"
               value="<?php echo $get['BillID']; ?>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="proname" name="productname" class="update"
               value="<?php echo $get['Productname']; ?>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="rate" name="rate" class="update"
               value="<?php echo $get['Rate']; ?>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="update"
               value="<?php echo $get['Quantity']; ?>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" class="update"
               value="<?php echo $get['Amount']; ?>">
      </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="sendvalue()">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

My script is

```
$('#bill').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
});

function sendvalue() {
  var prev = $('#bill').data('val');
  var current = $("#bill").val();
  //alert(prev+";"+current); 

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updateedit.php",
    data: ({
      previous: prev,
      currentvalue: current,
    }),
    success: function(data)  {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('failed');
    }               
  });
}
```

Comment: This is a more general comment: you should really look into [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) answers to your questions. It helps future visitors to see if an answer (and which one) helped you solve your questions.

Comment: use the `$(input[type=text])` or `$( ":text" )` selector

Comment: Have you considered a framework such as [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)?  Frameworks make things like this much easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all values of text inputs with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182528/how-to-get-all-values-of-text-inputs-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using id selector try to get by input type and make a jQuery.each() to get the results.

```
$.each($("input[type=text]"), function( index, value ) {
      //What you want to do for every text input
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First select all inputs by class `update` and attach an event lister for the focus event.

Then you can call `sendvalue` function and send an array of objects to bulk update all values to the backend (alter your php code to recieve an array instead of a single object)

```
$('input.update').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
});

function sendvalue() {
  // Array
  var postData = [];
  $('input.update').each(function() {
     var inp = $(this);
     postData.push({
        previous: inp.data('val'),
        currentvalue: inp.val()
     });
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updateedit.php",
    data: postData,
    success: function(data)  {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('failed');
    }               
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer @kapantzak I tried foreach($_POST['postdata'] as $value)  on my php page. But I didn't get any values how can I try else.

Comment: postData didn't get any values @kapantzak still. I am struck with it.